# WinSCP script does not work when run from Task scheduler

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, winscp

I am setting up the Task Scheduler to run a script that pulls data from WinSCP to another program, which then transmits the data to a report I use. The script takes the CDR files that are needed for that existing day pulls them to the RMST program and creates a temp file to hold that data until the old data transmits.

When I manually run the script which is a `.vbs`, it runs fine. The problem is when I set up the Task Scheduler to run the script, it states that it ran the action but the files are not transferred.

The User Account used has full admin rights and the the settings in the Task Scheduler are with the highest privileges.

Any idea on why the script is not running?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you enable session logging using the `/log` command line parameter. And inspect the log, to see, what's wrong.

For details see, [Debugging transfer task running in Windows Scheduler](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_debugging_scheduler).

As the article suggests, another good debugging practice is to wrap the WinSCP execution to a batch file, so that you can [capture its (error) output](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_debugging_scheduler#output).

Answer (score 0):

I initially had to set the environment variable for the PATH to include the directory where the executable for WinSCP.exe was in order to get the ability to manually call the .bat file with WinSCP.exe referenced in it, but it wasn't until I rebooted the machine that I was able to get the Scheduled Task calling WinSCP.exe successfully. Even though I manually ran the .bat file successfully after changing the PATH environment variable, a reboot was needed to get the scheduled task going for me.